# Continuous ajax calls makes application crash

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a html application which contains 4 ajax calls which runs continously every 2 seconds back to back. The objective is to read new and fresh data fron the db continuously and seamlessly.

```
 function messagesreceived(){

 var queryString = "XXXXXXXXX";
  $.ajax({
  url:queryString,
  'Content-Type':'application/json',
   method:'GET',
   dataType:'json',
   cache: false,
   success:function(data){
   displaymessages(data);
   rendermessagesreceived();
   },
  complete: function(xhr,status){
  setTimeout(messagesreceived,2000);
  },
 error: function(xhr,status){

if(xhr.status == 0){
 footerText.setText("NETWORK DISCONNECTED");
}else{
    footerText.setText("Something went wrong! Please reload the   page!");
 }
  }
   });
}


   function loadreadings() {

var queryString = "XXXXXXX";
$.ajax({
    url: queryString,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        mapreadings(data);
        plotreadings();
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        setTimeout(loadreadings, 2000);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
        if (xhr.status == 0) {
            footerText.setText("NETWORK DISCONNECTED");
        } else {
            footerText.setText("Something went wrong! Please reload the page!");
        }
     }
  });
}

 function loadreadings2() {
var queryString = "XXXXX";
$.ajax({
    url: queryString,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        initiate(data);
        footerText.setText("");
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
        setTimeout(loadreadings2, 2000);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {

        if (xhr.status == 0) {
            footerText.setText("NETWORK DISCONNECTED");
        } else {
            footerText.setText("Something went wrong! Please reload the page!");
        }
     }
  });
}
```

Its runs fine first 15/20 mins and then crashes. The below link is the screenshot of the error.

[image: App crashing error]]

can anyone please suggest how to resolve this. Its a very critical issue that I have been facing from past 15 days. Googled for the solution but no luck.

Appreciate your time and help.

Thanks.

Comment: One reason may be due to memory overuse. make sure that you are not appending big data into an array or object during each ajax call

Comment: try running it with the developer tools console open, monitor for any errors, monitor memory usage - try to do some *basic* debugging to see where you went wrong with your code

Comment: Yes @Prakash. I am using array to parse the response data and show it up in the application. But cleaning them too after the usage. Still, I dont understand, why it uses more moemory. Any alternative for this?